# Obtaining attachment download statistics in confluence or jira

Tags: java, jira, confluence

I have pages with attachments and I need statistics about their download counts.

What is the best way to obtain these statistics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the [`tracking-info`](http://wiki.customware.net/repository/display/AtlassianPlugins/tracking-info) macro, provided by the free [tracking-plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.customware.confluence.plugin.tracking):

```
{tracking-info:[Attachment Name]
   |value=[view count|first view date|last view date]
   |format=[date format]
   |digits=[#]}
Default text
{tracking-info}
```

Comment: oh thanks i'll try it, i also try to find a way how it works it need for me just for create my custom plugin

Comment: Great for Confluence, not for JIRA though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to track top downloaded files in a space, use the following:

```
    {tracking-table:spaces=@self|types=attachment|maxResults=10}
```